# read class and apply css with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, apply

I wanna apply css with short class name with number.

for example,

if I use class name `mt-100`, it means `margin-top:100px`.

if I use class name `mr-200`, it means `margin-right:200px`.

if I use class name `mt-100 mr-200`, it means `margin-top:100px` and `margin-right:200px`.

if I use class name `pt-100 mt-100 mr-200`, it means `padding-top:100px` and `margin-top:100px` and `margin-right:200px`.

I try to make it but it does not work.

I do not want to make every class in css like this --> `.mt-100{margin-top:100}`

could you help me how to do make this?

thank you in advance.

let me show you my code below,

---

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function classStartsWith(str) {
  return $('div').map( function(i,e) {
    var classes = e.className.split(' ');
    for (var i=0, j=classes.length; i < j; i++) {
      if (classes[i].substr(0, str.length) == str) return e;
    }
  }).get();
}
function classEndWith(str) {
  return $('div').map( function(i,e) {
    var classes = e.className.split(' ');
    for (var i=0, j=classes.length; i < j; i++) {
            if (classes[i].indexOf('mt-') || classes[i].indexOf('mb-') || classes  [i].indexOf('mr-') || classes[i].indexOf('ml-') || classes[i].indexOf('pt-') || classes[i].indexOf('pb-') || classes[i].indexOf('pr-') || classes[i].indexOf('pl-'))
    {
                    var ct = classes[i].split('-');
                    var cts = ct[1];
            }
      if (classes[i].substr(0, str.length) == str) return e,cts;
    }
  }).get();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(classStartsWith('mt-')).each(function(){
        $(this).css('margin-top', classEndWith('mt-')+'px');
    });
    $(classStartsWith('mb-')).each(function(){
        $(this).css('margin-bottom', classEndWith('mb-')+'px');
    });
    $(classStartsWith('mr-')).each(function(){
        $(this).css('margin-right', classEndWith('mr-')+'px');
    });
    $(classStartsWith('ml-')).each(function(){
        $(this).css('margin-left', classEndWith('ml-')+'px');
    });

    $(classStartsWith('pt-')).each(function(){
        $(this).css('padding-top',  classEndWith('pt-')+'px');
    });
    $(classStartsWith('pb-')).each(function(){
        $(this).css('padding-bottom',  classEndWith('pb-')+'px');
    });
    $(classStartsWith('pr-')).each(function(){
        $(this).css('padding-right',  classEndWith('pr-')+'px');
    });
    $(classStartsWith('pl-')).each(function(){
        $(this).css('padding-left',  classEndWith('pl-')+'px');
    });
});
    </script>

</head>


<body>

<div class="mt-100 mb-200" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid red">
aaaa
</div>
<div class="pt-200 mb-200" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid red">
bbb
</div>
<div class="pr-300 ml-300 mt300" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid red">
ccc
</div>
<div class="pl-200 mt200" style="width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid red">
ddd
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: why don't you use css class directly? like .mt-100 {margin-tope: 100px;}

Comment: Why don't you use `data` attributes? Like e.g. `<div data-width="200">...</div>`.

Comment: That does not make any sense, that is basically same thing as setting inline styles for the element. What is the need for this, there must be a better solution?

Comment: @Esa What does not make sense to you? The OP way or ...?

Comment: may be this helps http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/DecNq/

Comment: @MarkusHofmann the original question, I was considering the data-attributes and unobstrusive javascript myself as a solution for this.

Comment: There are multiple CSS pre-compilers like SASS which might be able to dynamically apply the right value according to the class of the element. However I can't confirm this because I've no actual experience using these kinds of tools.

Comment: @Noodlemanny SASS is a pre-processor. All sass files need to be converted into pure CSS before production release. So after changing into CSS the file is static. SASS is not something like jQuery which you can code to make dynamic changes.

Comment: @MarkusHofmann I hadn't realised OP wanted to perform dynamic tasks. Upon reflection I realise my suggestion doesn't work due to the fact that LESS obviously can't know what classes will be present in the DOM at the time of compile.

Comment: The reason why I wanna know this is I like to write every classes separately in my css. for example, when I just wanna give padding top 10px, I have to type in every div. I know I make some specific common div class and apply it but I like to use multiple classes in the div. that's why I wanna know how to do it. thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you handle it now presents way too much overhead for this kind of task.

I recommend you to learn more about using the `data` attribute on your HTML tags. These attributes allow you to define tag specific settings which you can easily read with jQuery and make it respond to the data.

Example:

```
<div class="my-div-class" data-mt="100" data-mb="200">...</div>
<div class="my-div-class" data-pt="200" data-mb="200">...</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        // Walk through each element with this class
        $('.my-div-class').each(function() {
            var thisDiv = $(this), // cache this element
                thisData = thisDiv.data(), // get all data attributes
                thisCSS = {}; // create the css array

            // Check which data is set and update the css accordingly
            if (thisData['mt']) {
                thisCSS['margin-top'] = thisData['mt'] + 'px';
            }
            if (thisData['mb']) {
                thisCSS['margin-bottom'] = thisData['mb'] + 'px';
            }
            if (thisData['pt']) {
                thisCSS['padding-top'] = thisData['pt'] + 'px';
            }
            if (thisData['pb']) {
                thisCSS['padding-bottom'] = thisData['pb'] + 'px';
            }

            // Add the css to this element
            thisDiv.css(thisCSS);

            // The following two lines show the data in each div for debugging. 
            // Remove these lines when you don't need this info anymore.        
            thisDiv.append('<div>CSS: ' + JSON.stringify(thisCSS) + '</div>');
            thisDiv.append('<div>DATA: ' + JSON.stringify(thisData) + '</div>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7j6Cp/).

And [here](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is the jQuery Documentation on `.data()`.

Also check out the `data-attribute` documentation [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute--webdesign-9642).

Comment: @user3811773 Nice to hear that you're happy with it :-) To finish up, please accept this answer.

Comment: is this support ie8 ? I tested padding is not working in ie8. but when I directly type in style attr or css, the padding is working.

Comment: Try adding the following into the header of your page `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`. [Here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/p/x-ua-compatible-meta-tag.htm) you can read more on what this does. Furthermore, use `<!DOCTYPE html>` to make sure you're using [HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Introduction_to_HTML5). Give this a try. Which version of jQuery are you using? In some older versions there are IE bugs.

Comment: I forgot to add meta tag and doctype :(...... I use 1.8.2 version of jquery. I think latest version of jquery is not compatible with ie8. I will test it tomorrow. thank you~